# ASA High Availability failover link configuration

Tags: cisco-asa, high-availability

According to the [Cisco ASA 5500 Series Configuration Guide](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa82/configuration/guide/ha_overview.html#wp1078844), Cisco's preferred method of configuring your network for ASA High Availability is as such:

[image: Cisco inter-switch-link configuration]

They have two switches on External, two switches on Internal and then two direct, non-switched connections between the two ASA units.

Why two links between the ASAs?

The *only* thing I can think of is that with a single failover link is that if the interface of the failover link fails, both switches will think that they are the primary unit (and hilarity ensues), and debugging which link has failed will be harder as both units will indicate that their interface is offline. However this seems right out there in terms of potential failures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your reasoning is right. Since the idea is to create a fully redundant failover solution then any single point of failure must be addressed. As you say if you don't have a Standy failover link then the failure of one port could cause a serious problem.

Since this in theory no less likely to happen than a failure on one of the other physical ports on the device it definitely seems like it needs to be planned for!

Comment: I guess so. I was thinking of failure modes like cables being unplugged, PSU's failing, switches failing. But you're right, if a single port fails it has a 1/4 chance of being the failover port.

Comment: Failover is always a pain really, the number of things you end up considering for it has always meant in my experience with SME's you are better off outsourcing!

Comment: Outsourcing failover?  What happens when the outsourcer fails?

Comment: More a case of outsourcing whatever you are trying to protect from failover. On an internal network you obviously have to do it yourself but most things, server applications, email etc are usually cheaper and easier to outsource to someone who already has the redundant infrastructure in place.